# How can I have multiple states in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, components

I have only one state for clicking on button but I have 10 button component.
How can I have multiple states without repeatly defining state

```
let [Clicked,setState] = useState(false)

const clicking =()=>{
setState(!Clicked)
}
```

this will apply on all buttons if I add `clicking` to all of my components , can you tell me how can i add for example `Cliked1` `Clicked2` etc for each component without defining `useState` all the time

Comment: have a single button component and then use it inside your parent component with high order array functions such as `map`.

Comment: @KavinduVlndika can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the button in a parent component

```js
  const MyButton = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

    return (<button
      onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
    />
  }
```

Then just have as many MyButtons as you want:

```js
  const MyComponent () => {
    return <>
      <MyButton/>
      <MyButton/>
      <MyButton/>
    </>
  }
```

It's not clear what you are trying to do with this state, so I'm assuming that the state only needs to be local.

Comment: just a moment. I'm gonna try

Comment: But how can I change state individually

Comment: When you click each button, the state in MyButton will change.

Comment: Each MyButton has it's own state

Comment: @Joji if this isn't the behaviour you want, can you explain what you expect your buttons to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using React [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) Method

Basically you make Wrapper Component which takes a function that returns a jsx

```
const CounterWrapper = ({ render }: any) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  return <>{render(count, increment, decrement)}</>;
};
```

and then in any of your component use can consume this common code as

```
<CounterWrapper
   render={(count: any, increment: any, decrement: any) => {
       return (
            <>
              Counter No.1 : {count}
              <br />
              <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
              <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
            </>
       );
    }}
/>
```

[Code SandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-props-stack-overflow-plo91)